# Why is my jquery code not working or throwing any errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can checkout my project here: http://jsfiddle.net/raj4dev/2o4uapc9/1/

**Summary:** I am making a jquery image slider. You can change the image in a box by pressing next and previous arrows. Currently, I have added code only for the next arrow.

**Issue:** Nothing happens when I click the next arrow. I don't see any errors in the chrome developer tools.

Please tell me how I can debug and fix this issue ?

**Code here.**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1>jQuery content slider</h1>
            </header>
            <img src="http://icongal.com/gallery/image/337589/small_arrow_left.png" alt="Prev" id="prev">
            <div id="slider">
                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="slide-copy">
                        <h2>Slide 1</h2>
                        <p>Dance and slide!</p>                     
                    </div>
                    <img src="http://m.rgbimg.com/cache1ny0NN/users/j/ja/jana_koll/600/mfOAUfa.jpg" alt="an image">
                </div>

                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="slide-copy">
                        <h2>Slide 2</h2>
                        <p>Dance and slide!</p>                     
                    </div>
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f9/2e/c0/f92ec0238d508e029be8b7163205d24e.jpg" alt="an image">
                </div>

                <div class="slide">
                    <div class="slide-copy">
                        <h2>Slide 3</h2>
                        <p>Dance and slide!</p>
                    </div>
                     <img src="http://www.pptbackgroundstemplates.com/backgrounds/abstract-red-light-wave-ppt-backgrounds-powerpoint.jpg" alt="an image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/saki/nuoveXT/128/Small-arrow-right-icon.png" alt="Next" id="next">
        </div>
    </body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sliding_speed = 500; 
    var autoswitch = true; 
    var autoswitch_speed = 4000;

    $('.slide').first().addClass('active');

    //Hide all slides, but...
    $('.slide').hide();

    //...show only the first slide
    $('.active').show();

    $('#next').on('click', function(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive'); /*'Hide the currently active slide and mark it as oldActive so that you can go back to it using the previous button.'*/
        if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
            $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
        }else {
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');  
        }
        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

#slider {
    width: 940px;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    border: #666 solid 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#silder img {
    width: 940px;
    height: 350px;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
}

.slide-copy {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #7f7f7f;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
}

#prev, #next {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

#prev {
    margin-right: -45px;
}

#next {
    margin-left: -45px;
}
```

Comment: The handler fires (I put a `console.log` inside of it) - your code just isn't doing what you think it should.

Comment: You're adding and removing the `active` class, but that class isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to again hide all slide and then show only the active one.  You are changing the classes to properly set your desired active slide to have the active class, but nothing says that all active slides are shown always and all other slides are hidden always.

http://jsfiddle.net/v1au2d57/

```
$('#next').on('click', function(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive'); /*'Hide the currently active slide and mark it as oldActive so that you can go back to it using the previous button.'*/
        if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
            $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
        }else {
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');  
        }
        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        //Hide all slides, but...
        $('.slide').hide();

        //...show only the first slide
        $('.active').show();
    });
```

Comment: a css style would have accomplished this too.

Comment: Indeed.  Probably a better approach.  I'm just using the same approach as supplied.

Comment: @stephen.vakil - I don't understand why we need to add the line $('.slide').hide(); initially and after clicking the next button. When I remove the hide lines, only one slide is visible. So, why do I need to hide the slides when they are already hidden ? Of course, if  don't hide the slides, the code does not work. But, I don't understand why. Please explain.

Comment: @KevinB - I tried using css `.active {visibility: visible;}` It did not work.

Comment: You are adding the .active class to the first slide and then instructing jQuery to "show" the current objects that have .active class.  When the user clicks next, you want to change which slide has the .active class and update the previous slide that has .active to be .oldActive.  So now you have a new slide which is currently invisible with a .active class and the previous slide, which is still visible, as .oldActive.  So you need to do something to hide .oldActive and show the new .Active.  You could also just do $('.oldActive').hide(); to accomplish the same effect.

Comment: @HelloWorldNoMore `display: none` and `display: block` would be more appropriate. display block for active, and display none for those without the active class.

Comment: @stephen.vakil - Can you please give me +1 to remove the -1 ? I am new to jQuery and my tutorial gave me the wrong code. I don't think that I should be punished for this. https://www.udemy.com/projects-in-javascript-jquery/learn/

Comment: @KevinB - Not sure what is the best way after I read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630945/is-there-an-opposite-to-displaynone

Comment: i assumed block, it could be block, inline, inline-block, or any one of the other valid values that isn't `none`