# css display property: make visible without setting the actual display type?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component which is wrapped in a div with `display: flex`

Another component controls whether that other component is visible or not. The initial state is `display: 'none'` and on a certain condition it will be shown. I wouldn't want to show it again by setting it to display flex, because I prefer that the component itself will be responsible for that. I would like to do something like "unset the `display: none` and let the component decide how it will be shown".

```
const AddNewRowHoverArea = styled('div')({
  height: 16,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  '& > div': {
    display: 'none',
  },
  '&:hover div': {
    display: 'flex',
  },
});
```

Currently it's done with `display: flex`. In such case is my only option is to use `visibility: hidden` ?

Comment: You can use the `unset` value, for example, `display: unset` on that other component you talked about. Or go with `visibility: hidden`. But I don't really understand what's purpose of this, since it's going to be the value going to be overridden by the down the tree `display: flex` anyway. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: Don't know reactjs, but could you do `&:not(:hover) > div : { display: 'none' }`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you question correctly ,You can undone display none like this:

```
$('#ur_element_id').css('display','block');
```

Comment: Actually you phrased the question much better than I, and I then found a thread discussing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630945/is-there-an-opposite-to-displaynone

I'm not using jquery, thank you very much however

Comment: you can use its alternative in vanilla js like this:

`document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like `display: initial` or `display: block`